# How to assign a shortcut key to send my system into hibernation?

Tags: shortcut-keys, hibernate

I want to assign a shortcut key for the Hibernate functionality. I have <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> for hibernation in Windows, but it's not working on Ubuntu. It's getting in sleep mode instead.

I've also tired changing the keyboard shortcut option as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> with command `pm-hibernate`, but still it didn't work. I referred [this Ubuntu Forums Thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=774376) but couldn't find any solution for this.

Any solution please?

Comment: Thank you every one for there comments. Finally I found something strange. I assigned the ctrl + H with command  pm-hibernate. Now my computer goes into Hibernate as follows: Step 1> ctrl+alt+T  Step 2> ctrl + H H H.... yes tap H three time it works ..strange but works..I dont know why ..

Answer (score 1):

If you need to setup hibernation shortcut sequence, you go to Ubuntu System settings (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and then typing `gnome-control-center`) and then choosing *keyboard settings*.

[image: Settings]

Under that, you will see a tab that says "shortcuts", and there will be an option to set a custom command :

[image: set custom command]

Then you will need to put the command you want to hibernate your computer.

Comment: I guess, you don't want to enter your password every time you hit those keys. Here's a command that does without one: `dbus-send --system --type=method_call --dest=org.freedesktop.UPower /org/freedesktop/UPower org.freedesktop.UPower.Hibernate`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, Hibernate will need to be enabled. Go into console and type

```
sudo gedit /var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/hibernate.pkla
```

In the new gedit window, copy-paste this in:

```
[Re-enable Hibernate]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
ResultActive=yes
```

Save and close the file, reboot the computer, and then you have it available as a menu option. Assuming you're on a laptop, the <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> shortcut should work afterwards as well, if this is a default option that came with the laptop (i.e. printed on the keyboard, etc.).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I already have hibernate setup as menu, as you did in your steps.I am able to select Hibernate from drop down menu.  But I am unable to assign any shortcut key for Hibernate. Is there any way that I can assign shortcut key to hibernate. Any customization?.

Comment: Did you try using fn + F11 after enabling Hibernate?

Comment: Yes it goes in suspend mode...